# overlay images depending on drop down options

Tags: image, drop-down-menu, overlay

What I'm trying to accomplish here is the following:

- Create a canvas where someone could choose from a variety of (dropdown menus)  guitars and as they choose parts of the image, the parts would display inside the canvas.
- So lets say someone is trying to chose the body color. There would be a menu with "body color" and the color options below it. As they choose a different color the same would change accordingly.
- Same thing with a "neck color" option. (Here is one of my issues)
- Same thing with a "hardware color" option.
- Same thing with a "pickguard color" option.

I was able to change the bodies color correctly but for some reason the body is being displayed twice.

When I choose the neck option it displays the correct neck but the body disappears.

Here is the code that I have developed so far but clearly not working as desired. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is what a have so far (see comment).

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#switchSel').change(function() {

var switchPic = $('.switch');
switchPic.removeClass();
switchPic.addClass('switch ' + $(this).val());
})
})

</script>
```

Comment: Here is my code: https://guitarfetish.3dcartstores.com/assets/images/30off/blendmode_plugin-example1.html